# Converting view to stored procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a view some thing like this. I have just given partial code here

```
DROP VIEW u_EVENT;

CREATE VIEW u_EVENT AS

 WITH time_summary_data
          AS (  SELECT   u_name,
                         u_id,
                         u_event_id,
                         --  max(d_report_date)   d_report_date,
                         --  max(d_time_from)  d_time_from,
-------
--
---
```

I am getting recordset from the view. Now I want to convert into a stored procedure. As a `with` clause is used, I don't understand how to do.

I tried with below one. It compiles successfully but not able to display record set.Am I doing correct or some other way to do. How to display record set, no idea. Is this Sp correct ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE TEST (p_param2 out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
open p_param2 for
WITH time_summary_data AS
```

Comment: what you want to do? i'am can't understand what you try to do.

Comment: I wan to create a stored procedure but as it is having with statement, it doesnt work

Comment: @aniltc. Does not work? Is that error on `create or replace`? Error when executing the stored procedure? If an error, copy error exactly into your question. Result of running is different? Then list expected and actual results. Can you reduce to a simple complete test case? You say having the `with` clause is the issue, can you get a similar stored procedure running correctly without the `with`?

Comment: My current view is not an optimised one so I am converting to stored procedure nad palaaning to insert into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, its the same as converting a view without any "WITH".

Say you have a simple view like below:

```
create or replace view Mark_Jones as
  with tbl(name, id) as (
             select 'MarkJones'  name , 1 id from dual
   union all select 'LemiWink'    , 2 from dual
   union all select 'ChinaLTD'    , 3 from dual
   union all select 'GrowsInvest' , 4 from dual     
  )
  select * from tbl
;
```

It shows:

```
SQL> select * from mark_jones;
MarkJones            1
LemiWink             2
ChinaLTD             3
GrowsInvest          4
```

I see no problem in *converting* (we don't really know what this can mean to you) it to a stored procedure:

```
 create or replace procedure proc_mark_jones(p_test out sys_refcursor) as
 begin
   OPEN p_test FOR   
     with tbl(name, id) as (
                select 'MarkJones'  name , 1 id from dual
      union all select 'LemiWink'    , 2 from dual
      union all select 'ChinaLTD'    , 3 from dual
      union all select 'GrowsInvest' , 4 from dual     
     )
     select * from tbl
     ;
 end;
 /
```

Here is how to use this procedure:

```
declare 
  x sys_refcursor;
  l_name varchar2(1000);
  l_id   number;
begin
  proc_mark_jones(x);
  IF (x IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    LOOP
      FETCH x INTO l_name, l_id;
      EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_id||'*    ' ||l_name);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE x;
  END IF;
end;
/

1*    MarkJones
2*    LemiWink
3*    ChinaLTD
4*    GrowsInvest

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

... worked for me on Oracle11g.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures do not send things to the screen.  You have to have several settings turned on to get anything to come to the screen:

If you are using sqlplus, you have to have this set:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

Inside your procedure, you have to put this to get the line to come to the screen:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line('Putting my stuff on the screen');
```

You cannot display a select from a table like you can with SQL server.

Comment: I don't think that's the point of the OP. He's not trying to display the ouput; He tries to ***convert*** a VIEW (DB object).